# How to loop through array in Ocaml to return a value?

Tags: arrays, ocaml

The instructions are

- initialize norm to 0.0
- loop through array
- add to norm the square of
  the current array component
- return norm

My code

```
type vector = float array
let norm_loop (vector: vector) =
  let norm = ref 0.0 in
  for x = 0 to (Array.length vector) - 1 do
    norm := (!norm +. (vector.(x)*.vector.(x)))
  done in
  norm
```

But when I type that into uTop it says

```
# let norm_loop (vector: vector) =
      let norm = ref 0.0 in
      for x = 0 to (Array.length vector) - 1 do
        norm := (!norm +. (vector.(x)*.vector.(x)))
      done in
      norm;;
Characters 4-13:
Warning 26: unused variable norm_loop.
- : float ref = {contents = 0.}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong for utop to think norm_loop is a variable. All I want to do is return `norm`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `in` is superfluous. There's no `let` that goes with it. Instead you should have this as the last few lines:

```
done;
!norm
```

Note that you were returning a reference, but you want to return a float (I assume). So you need to write `!norm` instead of `norm`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you could also use [`Array.fold_left`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Array.html) to achieve the same result:

```
let norm (vector : vector) = 
  Array.fold_left (fun acc v -> acc +. v *. v) 0.0 vector
```

Comment: Absolutely, using a fold is much more idiomatic OCaml. One reason to study OCaml is to see the power of immutable data (no references) and higher-order functions (like fold).